# userId не успевает добавится в апрос react-query

Tags: nextjs

я делаю такой запрос

```
  const { error, data: allPostsById } = useQuery(
    "postsById",
    () => getAllPostsByUserId(user.id),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
    }
  );
```

user.id я беру из редакса
затем когда я попадаю в

```
export const getAllPostsByUserId = async (userId: number) => {
  const { data } = await $host.get("api/post/getAllByUserId/" + userId);
  return data;
};
```

здесь userId сначала undefined, затем подгружается юзер из редакса и передается в getAllPostsByUserId и я вижу айдишник, (дебажил) из-за того что в первый раз мне приходит undefined запрос уходит с userId - undefined и остается в статусе pending, по идее нужно сделать так чтобы вот этот код

```
  const { error, data: allPostsById } = useQuery(
    "postsById",
    () => getAllPostsByUserId(user.id),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
    }
  );
```

срабатывал когда user будет не undefined и соответственно user.id уйдет правильный
Если попробовать вместо user.id захардкодить айдишник, написать 1, то запрос улетает отлично и ничего не падает,
подскажите как такое можно провернуть, еще раз говорю, у меня user лежит в редаксе (ну это пока) и появляется не сразу

юзера беру из редакса, а в редакс он записывается обычным запросом в useEffecte, диспатчем кладу в редакс стор, ну также кладу его в localStorage, но к нему не хочется привязываться

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userToken")) {
      check()
        .then((data) => {
          dispatch(setUser(data));
          dispatch(setAuth(true));
        })
        .catch(() => console.log("unauthorized"))
        .finally(() => {});
    }
  }, []);
```

вот функции логина регистрации и проверки сторажда

```
export const registration = async (user: any) => {
  const { data } = await $host.post("api/user/registration", user);

  localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.token);
  return jwt_decode(data.token);
};

export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  const { data } = await $host.post("api/user/login", { email, password });
  localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.token);
  return jwt_decode(data.token);
};

export const check = async () => {
  const { data } = await $authHost.get("api/user/auth");
  localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.token);
  return jwt_decode(data.token);
};
```

useQuery
вызываю в конпоненте Page по адресу localstorage:3000/Personal

const { error, data: allPostsById } = useQuery(
"postssById",
() => getAllPostsByUserId(user.id),
{
refetchOnMount: true,
staleTime: 100,
}
);

да че мелочиться - добавлю ка я весь файл, чтоб проще было подсказать)

```
"use client";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState, store } from "../../../store";
import Header from "@/components/Header/ui/Header";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer/ui/Footer";
import { addLike, getAllLikes } from "../../../API/likeAPI";
import { Box, Button, Container, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { check } from "../../../API/userApi";
import { setAuth, setUser } from "../../../store/slices/authSlice";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import {
  createPost,
  getAllPosts,
  getAllPostsByUserId,
} from "../../../API/postAPI";
import { addOneLike, setMyLikes } from "../../../store/slices/likesSlice";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import ColorButtons from "@/components/ColorButtons/ui/ColorButtons";
import { addOneMyPosts } from "../../../store/slices/postsSlice";
import intl from "react-intl-universal";
import { initLocales } from "../locales/initLocales";
import Post from "@/components/Post";
import { DEFAULT_COLOR, RUSSIAN, colors } from "../constants";
import DropzoneComponent from "@/components/Dropzone/ui/DropzoneComponent";
import { getLNG, getPostsByUserId, makeFormDataPost } from "../utils";
import { useMutation, useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import { $host } from "../../../API";

// TODO REMOVE ANY
const Personal = () => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState<string>(RUSSIAN);
  const { user, isAuth } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
  const [dropzoneFile, setDropzoneFile] = useState(null);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<object | null>(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState<string>(DEFAULT_COLOR);

  const { myLikes } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.likes);

  initLocales(language);
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    reset,
    formState: { isDirty, dirtyFields, touchedFields, errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
    },
  });

  const title = watch("title");
  const description = watch("description");

  async function createPo(post: any) {
    debugger;
    const { data } = await $host.post("api/post/create", post);
    return data;
  }

  const { error, data: allPostsById } = useQuery(
    "postssById",
    () => getAllPostsByUserId(user.id),
    {
      refetchOnMount: true,
      staleTime: 100,
    }
  );

  const mutation = useMutation((newPost) => createPo(newPost), {
    onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries("postssById"),
  });

  const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const uniquePostId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
    const formData = makeFormDataPost(
      data,
      date,
      uniquePostId,
      user,
      dropzoneFile,
      selectedColor
    ) as any;
    mutation.mutate(formData);
    reset();
    setDropzoneFile(null);
  };

  const getAllLikesHandler = async () => {
    try {
      await getAllLikes().then((likes) => dispatch(setMyLikes(likes)));
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  const addLikeHandler = async (uniquePostId: number) => {
    try {
      await addLike(uniquePostId, user.id, user.email).then((like) => {
        dispatch(addOneLike(like));
        getAllLikesHandler();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Something went wrong!");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userToken")) {
      check().then((data) => {
        dispatch(setUser(data));
        dispatch(setAuth(true));
      });
    }

    getAllLikesHandler();

    getLNG(language, setLanguage);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Header language={language} setLanguage={setLanguage} />

      <Box className="wrapper">
        <Container>
          <Typography typography="h6" textAlign="center" mt={3}>
            {intl.get("PERSONAL_AREA")}
          </Typography>
          <Typography textAlign="center">
            {intl.get("ALL_YOUR_POSTS")}
          </Typography>
          {allPostsById &&
            allPostsById
              .filter((item: any) => item.userId === user.id)
              .map((item: any, id: any) => (
                <Post
                  key={id}
                  myLikes={myLikes.filter(
                    (like) => like.uniquePostId === item.uniquePostId
                  )}
                  getAllLikesHandler={getAllLikesHandler}
                  addLikeHandler={addLikeHandler}
                  post={item}
                />
              ))}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" flexDirection="column">
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                {...register("title")}
                id="title"
                label="Title"
                variant="outlined"
                helperText={
                  touchedFields.title && !title
                    ? "is required"
                    : "make up new title"
                }
                error={touchedFields.title && !title}
              />
              <TextField
                margin="normal"
                {...register("description")}
                id="description"
                label="Description"
                variant="outlined"
                multiline
                maxRows={5}
                error={touchedFields.description && !description}
                helperText={
                  touchedFields.title && !title
                    ? "is required"
                    : "type here what you did today"
                }
              />
              <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-around">
                {colors.map((item, id) => (
                  <ColorButtons
                    key={id}
                    setSelectedColor={setSelectedColor}
                    selectedColor={selectedColor}
                    item={item}
                  />
                ))}

                <DropzoneComponent
                  setDropzoneFile={setDropzoneFile}
                  dropzoneFile={dropzoneFile}
                />
              </Box>
              <Button
                disabled={!title || !description || !dropzoneFile}
                sx={{ my: "10px" }}
                color="success"
                variant="contained"
                type="submit"
              >
                Share
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </form>
        </Container>
        <Box className="footer">
          <Footer />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Personal;
```

Главное что вот здесь
const { error, data: allPostsById } = useQuery(

```
    "postsById",
    () => getAllPostsByUserId(user.id),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
    }
  );
```

метод getAllPostsByUserId работает, если передать туда число захардкоженное, то есть действительно проблема в том, что user.id не успевает прийти в getAllPostsByUserId уходит undefined, как бы придумать чтобы react query перезапршивал данные, если user.id
изменился, типа как в useEffecte зависимости, ну я чет не соображу пока(

Comment: где вызывается useQuery? как получается `user`?

Comment: я добавил больше описания в сам вопрос

Comment: ну в общем я сделаль вот так и это работает, но выглядит криво     () => getAllPostsByUserId(user.id | Number(localStorage.getItem("userId"))),